# Asymptotic density of winning positions in "Prime Nim"?

Tags: prime-numbers, nim

Consider a single-pile NIM variant, played under standard (not misere) objective, with the rule that you may remove any *prime* number from the pile.  The winning positions of this game are all numbers $a_n$ where $a_0 = 0$ and for $A \equiv \{a_n\}$ consists of all numbers which are *not* of the form $p+a_k : p \text{ prime}, k<n$.
(This sequence appears, to 10,000 terms, in OEIS as [A025043](https://oeis.org/A025043).)

What is the asymptotic density (and if that is zero, bounds on a counting function) of winning positions?

Knowing the counting function of primes, one can frame a probabilistic argument about the likelihood that a given number $k \in A$ by solving an integral equation that looks something like
$$ D(x) = 1 - \int_1^u\frac{D(u)}{\log u} du
$$
(and you don't even have to solve the equation, just determine the asymptotic behavior of the solution). 
But that, of course, does not prove anything, since the primes could easily conspire to make the distribution different than that naive probability argument would suggest.

Comment: The integral equation is clearly wrong. If probability that $u$ is in the set is $D(u)$ and all of these are somehow independent, then the probability that $x$ is in not in the set is $\prod_u (1-D(x-u)/\log u)$. Assuming continuous approximation, this gives $\exp(-\int \frac{D(x-u)}{\log u}\,du)$. Of course, the events are not independent, and one has to worry (at bare minimum) about local factors coming from the fact that most primes are not divisible by $n$, for any fixed $n$

Comment: If you replace the primes by the squares, then the density of winning positions is zero. Indeed, if $W$ is a set of winning positions, then $W-W$ contains no squares, which by Sarközy's theorem implies that $W$ has zero density. Sadly, this does not directly work on the primes since the difference set of $4\mathbb{N}$ contains no primes.

Comment: The obvious conjecture is that the density of winning positions $\rho(n)$ goes to $C/\sqrt{\ln n}$ and numerical work makes it seem that $C \approx 19$.  But that is not even a hint at a proof of the general form of the counting function or density.